# Understanding proof that involves distance between 2 weighted variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

The problem reads like this:

> Let a and b be two rational number, such that a < b.
>
> Show that $\frac 1 3a+\frac 2 3b$ is closer to b than to a.

The proof:

> The distance between a and $\frac 1 3a+\frac 2 3b$ is
>
> $(\frac 1 3a+\frac 2 3b) - a = ...=\frac 2 3 (b - a)$
>
> The distance between $\frac 1 3a+\frac 2 3b$ and b is
>
> $b - (\frac 1 3a+\frac 2 3b) = ...=\frac 1 3 (b - a)$

I don't quite get why in the first distance we use $(...) - a$ and in the second distance we use $b - (...)$. Why isn't it $(...) - b$?

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere along the way, they say that $a<b,$ since otherwise you'd need to add absolute value signs to these equations (a distance should be positive).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet oh yeah, that is true, it's defined in a problem before this one. Let me add that.

Comment: @Max Once $a \lt b$ you have that $a \lt x=a/3+2b/3 \lt b\,$, so the distances to the endpoints are $\,|x-a|=x-a\,$ and $\,|x-b|=b-x\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, I think I understand. Because I know that one third of a plus one third of b will be smaller than b, I subtract that _from_ b. Got it now - you may want to add that as answer, I can accept that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\,x = \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{2}{3} b\,$. Given that $\,a \lt b\,$ it follows that $a \lt x \lt b\,$:

$$
a \;=\; \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{2}{3} a \;\lt\; \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{2}{3} b \;\lt\; \frac{1}{3}b + \frac{2}{3} b \;=\; b
$$

Then the distances to the endpoints are $\,|x-a|=x-a\,$ and $\,|x-b|=b-x\,$, and:

$$
|x-a|=x-a=\frac{2}{3}(b-a) \;\gt\; \frac{1}{3}(b-a) = b - x = |x-b|
$$